# Extract the most important for description of the object real values

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I want to implement convolutional neural network for extracting real values of the features from the image.

I understand that metric learning network tries to learn the most important things of the objects and then it outputs a vector of the abstract descriptors which should be almost the same for the same objects, but how can I get vector of the most important real-world values(e.g. width, area or color of the some local feature, so changing width of something on the image should change only responsible for it value or values) instead of this abstract vector, using something similar to the ResNet or another architecture?

I already tried to search something about this type of metrics or features extraction but it's nothing.

Also as I said it's not only metric extraction, net should find(as ResNet do it) and output non-abstract descriptors.

I understand that computer sees only pixels and so on, but in the learning process neural net learns the most important for description of the objects metrics, so these metrics should be some real-world values(or could be simply converted into them).

Of course any help or hints from you will be very useful!

Answer (score 1):

This topic is quite broad, so the answer depends on the kind of data you have (labelled, unlabelled, intersecting labels, partial labels). So, actually I could recommend several approaches. Hope it will help.

---

Assuming you have some kind of unsupervised (like auto-encoders) or semi-supervised CNN  and talking about some kind of "context" (compressed features). Learning important features basically means getting rid of noise. The definition of noise depends on the way you regularize or supervise your network (it might be "oversized" features, "changing too fast", "doesn't help classification" etc.), so the the behavior of your CNN.

In order to get real-valued outputs you have to use CNN for regression instead of classification - so no sigmoid "outputs" (for context) then. Another option is to encode "levels" of width as classes (if you don't need precise results).

So now, you have to extract some meaning from it...

In order to return something understandable, the network has to know something about what you actually mean by "meaningful representation". So I guess you need to provide targets for some of your data:

- you could provide width and other known metrics as a target (you'll have to scale it in advance)
- you can label existing output features, learned in unsupervised way if they correlate with features of interest. The important thing here is to specify some prior knowledge with regularization (for instance adversarial examples that randomly change irrelevant metrics).
- if one output-feature represents several features of interest - you can apply ICA (independent component analysis) in order to separate them.
- If you care about actual objects (want to manipulate with one particular object from your image) - you can subtract feature-vectors (vector-of-interest "minus" vector-extracted-from-irrelevant-data) in order to get only related features.

If you don't provide any targets - you'll have to find correlations with real-data manually.

---

If you work with CNN-based classifier and want to know where exactly classified object is on the scene, you'll probably need "Scene Labeling" - it labels every pixel with a class - so you can get a complete "mask" for your object (and simply extract metrics from it). Example of adding labels to pixels: [Convolutional Networks in Scene Labelling](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/ashwinpp_final_report.pdf)

---

Another example is [cat metrics converted to images](http://www.recode.net/2017/2/23/14702058/cat-image-machine-learning). It's based on the adversarial training, so instead of supervision, you could just modify your data in a way that makes features of interest most important.

Comment: [1/2 part] Many thanks for your answer! I found a few interesting things in your answer, but something not clear for me. Let's try to consider this algorithm on the example.  Supposably we have task to describe and recognize faces using this algorithm, it almost like metric learning do it, but we need to find and output the most important for description and recognition real values(e.g. distance between eyes, depth of eyes, coords of nose, color of lips etc.) using CNN(or another machine learning method)...

Comment: [2/2 part] ...So how our pipeline will be look? As I understood, of course it will be more like regression. Also we will provide different photos of one person, so network will know with which invariant features it need to work. In addition we can add scene labelling to split face to custom sectors(like eye, nose, mouth etc.). But I still can't see our workflow in steps. Maybe it will be more clear for me if you describe it on the this example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically, there is two approaches. [1/2]: you do scene labelling and just calculate metrics with formula. For eyes, algorithm can return you two masks, so you can calculate distance between (centroids of masks). When you get mask for lips - you can just calculate average color. And so on...So the first part of your pipeline is scene labeling, second - is hard-coded feature extractors

Comment: [2/2] Instead of hard coded feature extractors from scene-labels, you can specify targets on your own (it would make sense especially if you need measurements expressed in centimeters - it definitely won't be any precise). Which means that instead of (or better - in combination with) learning pixel-labels you can specify few more output features: lips color (scaled to be in 0..1, or embedded one hot vector for known colors), distance between eyes, depth of eyes etc. So, in that case it's just same old supervized learning and you have to specify distance, color, manually for many examples.

Comment: @don-prog talking about pipe-line in [2/2], I think combining it with scene labeling will help (as algorithm will learn distinct zones, which is useful for metrics extraction). You can either have two networks in pipeline: 1) extract masks, 2) pass masked values to metrics learners. Or just add more output neurons to your scene-labelling CNN. P.S. Basically, MLP can approximate any function given enough examples, so the only challenge here is to provide it with enough capacity, labels and examples.

Comment: [1/4] Thanks for explanation, it's looks clearly for me. So, we have two approaches. First: scene labeling(splitting/segmentation) on the needed sectors, and calculating some hardcoded features(distances, colors etc.). Second: supervised CNN, which need input X and output Y. Where X - photo, and Y - vector of extracted real values, so we need to decide which features we are need, measure and provide these vectors of values Y on the learning stage.  Additional approach is to add a scene labeling in the second approach. Is it correct understanding of your ideas?

Comment: [2/4] Also I think we missed one very important detail: I don't need hand-picked features, but I need n most important for describing and recognition features which will be picked using machine learning. After that, algorithm will output this Y vector of n elements, where each element will describe some real feature.

Comment: [3/4] I even don't need Y with some real measurement units(e.g. centimeters), some abstract units will be enough. It's like character constructor in Sims - we have many the most important tunable features(eyes/nose/lips color, size, shape, position) which can describe almost all faces in the one vector(which contains these features values even in some abstract units).

Comment: [4/4] The some standard metrics learning methods(like ResNet) really suitable, except that if I change, for example, eyes color, then almost all of the Y vector will change. But I want to change only value which describe eye color. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: @don-prog About (1/4), yes it's correct. The problem about extracting most important features is that most important features for machine are features that **explain** the input data, so set of *automatically learned* features depends on the data you provide and for denoising auto-encoders - the way you add noise. So basically if you want such encoder to learn about distance between eyes - you have to provide it with examples of image with changed everything but eye distance and make it encode it back to "normal". Or change eye distance and push auto-encoder to "re-encode" it.

Comment: Simply saying, you have to make machine to pay attention to the details that matter to you. By default it has no notion of the distance between eyes, even if some feature represents it most, it still sensitive to the noise from other parameters (like maybe size of the eye). So adversarial learning could help to make it to pay more attention (like in that edges2cats they made it to pay more attention to cat's shape: http://www.recode.net/2017/2/23/14702058/cat-image-machine-learning).

Comment: btw, technically, when I'm talking about features that explain the data (for unsupervised case), it means that the samples you provide lie near lower-dimensional manifold (with less features), I've got some illustrations in [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261265/factor-analysis-vs-autoencoders/261270#261270) - so the shape of this manifold (hypersurface) depends on samples, they describe our prior belief about variations (different eye distance, nose coordinates etc.) that are possible

Comment: As always, many thanks for your help, and sorry for the late reply.
1. You said that if I want to use auto-encoders then I need to train them using images with changed everything but eye distance. Is it possible to automate process of learning instead of manual changing of images?

2. As I wrote before, originally the problem was due to changing all of the vector Y instead of changing a few values which are responsible for specific region. So maybe it is possible to make changing of Y values more intellectual(change, for example, eyes color will change only a few values in the Y vector)?

Comment: 3. Maybe it's possible to create net which will generate Y vector from face, and another net which will generate face using this Y vector which will very similar to the first face? And changing of some Y value will change only some feature(as in the example with the character constructor), e.g. changing first value will change some characteristic of nose.

Comment: 4. The convolutional neural nets like ResNet get feature maps related to the images which they are used for learning, so face recognition CNN will produce different separate face features which are very applicable for my purpose, are you sure that I really can't use it somehow?
5. Unfortunately I don't understand how you suggest to use adversarial learning and what are you meant in the your last comment ("it means that the samples you provide lie near lower-dimensional manifold...").

Comment: 6. After all our clarifications what do you suggest to use for my purpose(automatically learn and extract the most important for description of the object separate features like in the character constructor example)?

Comment: 1. if you can detect eyes and group images with similar distance - maybe, I'm just guessing 2. I think, we're running circles :), if there is no information about importance of eyes color - machine can't do it, sometimes it's just there sometimes you need <see my prev comments> 3. only if nose is different and you push network to restore it back, same story again

Comment: 4. If you put many faces to the network - it will learn important characteristic needed in order to recognize similar faces, I'm not saying - it definitely won't be what you need, but just imagine how important for you is let's say distance between eyes, when you can just look at head's shape, or neck length, or even worse - some shared characteristic  (like skin color).

Comment: 5. it was more technical comment, I actually provided a link about factor analysis there. 6. I actually suggested several methods, did you try any of them; this task as a new to me as for you, maybe even more. Basically, I'm just brainstorming, so it's hard to proceed without actual experiments :)

Comment: Simplest thing you could try (I actually assume you did) is to reduce number of features, it won't get you exactly what you want, but at least you might get which parameters exactly aren't being learned or find reasons why they're mixed together

Comment: Ok, I understood, need some additional research :) And I think the last question: can you clarify how can adversarial learning help me with my purposes?

Comment: [adversarial network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07004.pdf) is just denoising auto-encoder, it makes network's output more "realistic". I mean how many ways there is to modify distance between eyes? machine could just take an eye and move it out without changing face, right? P.S. I think your confusion comes from Wiki - they say it's all about informational security, which is not entirely true. Anything that could distinguish a fake input is an adversarial network.

Comment: If you look into Goodfellows book on deeplearning (it's free) they provide example where very small change (that our brain can't even catch) in an image of cat (or some other animal, I don't remember) can make the network recognize it as a dog :). So learning to resist adversarial changes make network more robust; for instance, if you don't care about who's face is gonna be at the output, you could directly use img2img for your purpose- just generate a simple geometric shape - and you'll get a more or less real face with all characteristics you want.